# Kind of null variable IOS

Tags: ios, debugging, null

i am actually debugging my iOS Application: i want to test if a variable is null or not:

Stupid question huh !

```
if (var !=nil) { doSomeWork ; }
```

So if the variable var is equal to nil and we want to print this result in the debugger area we will have something like that:

2012-10-12 21:33:01.553 Application's Name [892:13d03] (null)

This is cool, but indeed when i try to print the variable content in the debugger area, it has been showing :

2012-10-12 21:33:01.553 Application's Name [892:13d03] < null >

Can you tell me guys what is the difference between this two kinds of null, and how can i test if the second one is equal to nil.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second output, `<null>`, comes from the `NSNull` singleton. This is a class called `NSNull` that has a class method `+null` that returns the same singleton instance of `NSNull` every time. The primary purpose of this class it to be able to act as a stand-in for `nil` in places where you can't put `nil`, such as in collections. For example, JSON libraries typically return `NSNull` when the JSON includes `null`.

You can test for this simply by asking if it's `==` to `[NSNull null]` (since it's a singleton), or possibly if `[obj isKindOfClass:[NSNull null]]`. You could use `[obj isEqual:[NSNull null]]` if you like. You could even ask if it's `== kCFNull` if you want, since `CFNull` and `NSNull` are toll-free bridged. Whatever style you want is up to you.

Comment: "since CFNull and NSNull are toll-free bridged" that's not documented

Comment: @user102008: Huh, you're right. But it's pretty easy to verify. If you evaluate `[kCFNull class]` you get back `NSNull`. Additionally, `kCFNull == [NSNull null]` is true (since it's a singleton).

Answer (score 0):

`NSNull` it is class, `nil` is not. So if you are comparing `nil` with something you should use "`==`", if `NSNull` then -> `if ([var isEqual:[NSNull null]]) { ....}`